# Cardinal of $C:= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | (y+2x \land x+2y )\in \mathbb Q \right\} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the cardinals of :

1. $C:= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | (y+2x \land  x+2y )\in \mathbb Q \right\} $
2. $D:= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 |xy-x-y \in \mathbb {R/Q} \right\} $

My try and what giving me trouble :

1. $|C| \leq|\mathbb R^2|=|\mathbb R|=\aleph$.

and i know that if $x+2y \in \mathbb Q$ so

obviously $y+2x \in \mathbb Q$ (am i right ?)
and we can say $x+y \in \mathbb Q$.

I dont know how to continue and prove that $\aleph \leq |C|$

I think i made it complicated than what it supposed to be.

Help please ?

Comment: The cardinality of the continuum is typically denoted by $\mathfrak{c}$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$. $\aleph_\alpha$ ($\alpha$ an ordinal) is used to denote the $\alpha$-th cardinal.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. If $x = \pi$ and y = $-\pi/2$, then $x+2y\in \mathbb{Q}$ but $y + 2x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What does $y + 2x \land x + 2y$ mean?

Comment: $y+2x \in \mathbb Q$ and $x+2y \in \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $C$, if $y+2x \in \Bbb Q$ and $x+2y \in \Bbb Q$, then $4y+2x \in \Bbb Q$ so $3y \in \Bbb Q.$  Thus, $y \in \Bbb Q$ so $\vert C \vert \leq \aleph_0$.  Since $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q \in C$, we also have $\vert C \vert \geq \aleph_0$, so equality follows.

For $D$, note that $xy-x-y=(x-1)(y-1)-1 \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \iff (x-1)(y-1) \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, so $D= \{ (x, y) \mid (x-1)(y-1) \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \}$.  If $x \in \Bbb Q \setminus \{ 1 \}$, then $(x, y) \in D$ for any $y \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$.  Therefore, since $\vert \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \vert = 2^{\aleph_0}, \vert D \vert \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.  Since $\vert \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \vert = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and $D \subseteq \Bbb R \times \Bbb R, \vert D \vert \leq \vert \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \vert = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and  equality follows.